# Fixed sidebar next to a centered blogpost

Tags: html, css

for a page with a lot of text, readers should be able to navigate between sections with ease. As such I want to present an Index on the left-hand side of the main text that is permanently visible. The main text should be centered and should fill about 75% of the screen.

I have been messing around for a few hours but I just can't seem to get it right. Either the columns are overlapping, or there is white-space between them and won't center nicely.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="row">
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul> Content
            <li><a href="#Guidelines">Guidelines</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#Geographic Focus">Geographic Focus</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#Fields of Interest">Fields of Interest</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
   <div id="content">
                <div id="blog">
                </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper .row {
    display: flex;
    border-style:solid;
    width:100%;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content: center;
    align-self:center;
}          

#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  display:flex;
  border-style:solid;
  min-height:100vh;
  color:black;
  flex-direction:column;
  padding-top:70px;
  width: auto;
}

#blog {
  float: left;
  width:75%;
  padding:0;
  border-style:solid;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet below gives you an initial shot with minimal changes to your original code.

Still there might be better ideas. This idea places a fixed block, as requested, with 25% width and ensures, that the main content respects this 25% as a left-margin.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#sidebar {
  background: red; /* for visual testing */
  position: fixed;
  min-height:100vh;
  padding-top:70px;
  width: 25%;
}

#blog {
  background: blue; /* for visual testing */
  width:75%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul> Content
            <li><a href="#Guidelines">Guidelines</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#Geographic Focus">Geographic Focus</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#Fields of Interest">Fields of Interest</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   <div id="content">
        <div id="blog">
            Test text.
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, thanks a ton! I used `float:right` on the index to make it hug the blog-post

Answer (score 2):

*Updated based on comment*

In addition to `grid`, use `flexbox` to move the navigation towards the content

*Original answer*

You could create this layout using CSS Grid. Example:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
}

#sidebar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#sidebar ul {
  position: fixed;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav id="sidebar">
    <ul> Content
      <li><a href="#Guidelines">Guidelines</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#Geographic Focus">Geographic Focus</a> </li>
      <li><a href="#Fields of Interest">Fields of Interest</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="blog">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore praesentium sit, magnam voluptate pariatur harum veniam nostrum explicabo quibusdam mollitia vel blanditiis qui, voluptates totam, alias rerum sequi, eveniet. Iusto.</p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I implement your suggestions, the sidebar does stick, but it will hug the left-hand side of the frame, leaving white-space between the two columns. I'd like it to float to the right, and hug the main text, which should take the center spot at the stage.
Similarly, if I add a third column on the right, and divide the grid 15% 70% 15% there is still a big white-space on both sides. Which is strange, as I don't have any padding added (I put "padding: 0" on #blog and #sidebar)

Comment: @PaulCudles Apologies, I missed the part about keep the sidebar close to the main text. Updated answer. If you created a third column (15% 70% 15%) it will add 15% whitespace to the layout unless you have anything in it.

Comment: @PaulCudles Also, best to avoid mixing float with newer layout systems like flexbox and grid.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fixed position and add this to your #sidebar

```
#sidebar {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 21px;
}
```

**Don't forget to override the sticky position on small screens :)**

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the sidebar still hugs the left-hand side of the frame. I'd like it to hug the central column with the text. How would we do that?